# Jasypt 1.9 : Encrypting passwords with exclamation

Tags: java, password-encryption, jasypt

I am using Jasypt 1.9, and when I try to encrypt a password with exclamation it fails. It works fine without exclamation

for ex:

```
./encrypt.sh input="abc!abc"
-sh: !abc": event not found
```

Jasypt claims it is fixed here.. http://www.jasypt.org/changelogs/jasypt/ChangeLog.txt

Note:

```
 ./encrypt.sh input="abc\!abc" works, but decrypting produces the "abc\!abc"
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the passwords he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double. With double quotes, the shell first tries to expand `!abc` as a history event, giving you that error. Text in single quotes is not expanded.

This is a linux shell feature, and has nothing to do with Jasypt. The shell is expanding the expression before it executes anything.

Comment: This fails for ^ character.